# How to track multiple class instantiations from user entry into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, dictionary

I am trying to set a function which tracks each multiple instantiation of a class using the users input as the key and value (object name).  This first part seems to work but then I want to be able to search using the keywords of "name" and any other attribute in this case "age", and if in dictionary return the name and attribute.

The problem I have been trying top solve is taking a user entry and making this the name and representation string of the class, and further recording a list of all instantiations made against these user names.  The only way I can see to do this is by instantiating from a container such as list or dictionary.

```
class text:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

lst={}
def user():    
    x=input("Enter Class name: ")
    lst[x]= x
    y=input("Enter age: ")
    create(x,y)

def create(x,y):
    lst[x]=text(lst[x], y)

def search(x,m):

    for i in lst:
        if i == x:
            return(lst[x].m)
        else:
            print("not found")
```

Within the Search function I expect lst[x] to be passed user input string x and find the associated object which it does.  I then expect m to pass the string attribute passed in search, in this case age and then print name and age.  I have had this working but now it just seems to pass m rather than age?
So using Search('martin', 'age') I would expect it to return;
martin
50
if user() entered x='martin' and y=50.

I would be grateful for any help in getting m to pass the .age attribute??
Thanks
Martin

Comment: `lst[x].m` shouldn't work if `m` is a string. Instead you should use `getattr` function to access the respective attribute then call it properly.

Comment: `for i in lst:if i == x:` is the same as simply `k = lst.get(x,None); if K is None: print("not found")` without iterating the dictionary until x is found ... I still can't quite get what you want to achieve...

Comment: also: create(x,y) gets the x and y - why not simplyfy it and remove the `lst[x]= x` from user() and use `def create(x,y): lst[x]=text(x, y)` ... or inlie this line into user()

Comment: Patrick, I am trying to keep track of multiple instances of class, which it seems to me can only be achieved by instantiating from within a container such as a list or dictionary.  I then want to be able to search as to whether a particular instance of a user name exists or not.  If it exists return the attribute selected within the search.

Comment: Because the x and y are derived from user input first?

Comment: Kasramvd would you be kind enough to indicate how I use getattr in this code?

Comment: Patrick and Kasramvd, I have implemented both of your suggestions to get this code working the way I wanted.  Thankyou very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class text:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

lst={}

def user():    
    x=input("Enter Class name: ")
    lst[x]= x
    y=input("Enter age: ")
    create(x,y)

def create(x,y):
    lst[x]=text(lst[x], y)

def search(x,name):

    **k = lst.get(x,None)
    if k == None:
        print("not found")
    else:
        return getattr(lst[x], name)**
```